# Python Discord bot is not working in two days

Tags: python, discord, chatbot

I'm trying to create a Python Discord bot. This is a simple bot
but since yesterday the bot is not working; the commands do not work and Pycharm IDE is not showing any error code.

Here is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

TOKEN = "Token"

intents = discord.Intents.default()

bot = Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("Hello World!")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: `TOKEN` shouldn't be `"Token"`. It should be an actual token that you got from Discord. It's basically a password.

Comment: Oh Stef Thank you for help me

but Token will never Shown another people

so i write temporary code

Comment: Try it with `from discord.ext import commands` and then use `commands.Bot` and actually define some intents as you just stated you want to use the `default()` ones. (For example, if you have ticked members intent in the Discord Developer Portal, use `intents.members = True`

Answer (score 0):

change `intents = discord.Intents.default()` to `intents = discord.Intents.all()`

open developer portal and also enable all intents like in the picture from this link.
[enable intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NctQi.png)